# Flex: how to change the volume of an EMBEDDED sound?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, audio

Searching for how to change the volume of sounds, I always get this irritating `snd=new Sound(URLRequest)`, followed by `snd.setVolume(val)`. Oh, fine, but my sound is not an URLRequest, it's an embed.

I've made a lot of random attempts (1) to no avail. How am I supposed to do that instead?

(1) including casting my class to Sound, creating a Sound with the embed class as argument, <s>creating a SoundTransform and setting it to the channel</s>, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instantiate your embedded class like this:

```
[Embed(source="MySound.mp3")]
public var soundClass:Class;


protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    var smallSound:Sound = new soundClass() as Sound;
    var trans:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(.01);
    smallSound.play(0,0,trans);
}
```

Update:

In case what you really wanted to know was how to change the volume if the sound was already playing:

```
[Embed(source="MySound.mp3")]
public var soundClass:Class;
public var smallSound : Sound;
public var vol : Number = 0.01;
public var trans : SoundTransform;

public var chan : SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void {
    smallSound = new soundClass() as Sound;
    trans = new SoundTransform(vol);
    chan = smallSound.play(0,0,trans);
}

protected function volUp_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    vol += .1;
    trans = new SoundTransform(vol);

    chan.soundTransform = trans;
}
```

Comment: Yes I wanted to change the volume of a sound already playing. The SoundTransform worked, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the post. Interesting that I had to re-assign the entire soundTransform property to a new instance of SoundTransform and that only setting the volume attribute on soundTransform doesn't work